# Помогите с подключением java к базе данных MySQl(phpMyAdmin)

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных

Помогите! Сделал базу данных MySQL под управлением phpMyAdmin. И создал там таблицу.
Использую библиотеку MySQL_Connector.
Для того чтобы получить из неё данные я использую этот код:

```
try{
            Connection connection;
            String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName(driverName);
            String baseName = "ej3";
            String serverName = "localhost";
            String _url = "jdbc:mysql://"+serverName+"/"+baseName;
            String userName = "root";
            String password = "";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(_url, userName, password);
            String ask = "SELECT * FROM pupils";
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(ask);
            String tempN,tempSN;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                tempN = rs.getString("fName");
                tempSN = rs.getString("sName");
                addPupil(new Pupil(tempN, tempSN));
            }
            connection.close();
        }catch(Exception e){}
```

Он работает.
А как сделать так, чтобы не получать значения, а записывать?

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается при подключении?

Comment: Ну так это... вместо SELECT написать INSERT...

Comment: У Вас Название вопроса неправильно сформулировано, Вам не помощь с подключением и не с Джавой нужна. Вам SQL нужно выучить. И если коротко, то да...Вам нужен `INSERT` http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_operator_insert.html

Comment: Вместо executeQuery можно посмотреть executeUpdate.

Comment: Я пробовал место SELECT * FROM pupils писать INSERT INTO pupils(fName, sName) VALUES ('Vasa','Peta') но не помогает.

Comment: stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO pupils(fName, sName) VALUES ('Vasa','Peta')");

И сразу читать про 
prepareStatement()